# File transfer gone wrong

Tags: linux, wget

Newbie here

I am trying to transfer backup files of several servers to a central server, using wget, using a script and a cronjob. But when the last file is being transferred, something goes wrong and the file does not transfer completely. I have tried to use the debug feature, but it doesn't seems to give a file with the information with the error. Any ideas of how to get the file with the debug information?

```
wget --user $USER --password $PASSWORD "ftp://$2/backup/Backup_$1.zip" --debug   "/d/backup/server/NodesBackups/Backup_$1.zip"
```

I used the code line that Freddy showed, but I am still having issues. The file only shows the debug information of 2 of 4 of the backup files, although the script transferred the 4 files. And the last file was not completely transferred (this is the issue has was trying to investigate with the debug file).

Answer (score 0):

To save the debug output to a logfile instead of printing it to stderr, you can use the

- `-o logfile` / `--output-file=logfile` 
  or the
- `-a logfile` / `--append-output=logfile` option.

The first one overwrites an existing logfile and the latter appends to an existing logfile.

Assuming that `"/d/backup/server/NodesBackups/Backup_$1.zip"` is the path of the saved output file, you should use the `-O file` / `--output-document=file` option.

Example appending the output to `/tmp/debug.log`:

```
wget --user="$USER" --password="$PASSWORD" --debug -a /tmp/debug.log -O "/d/backup/server/NodesBackups/Backup_$1.zip" "ftp://$2/backup/Backup_$1.zip"
```